# Can I pass along JWT authorization from spring RestController to external back end API

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot BFF with a very simple jQuery page as front end.
The BFF requires OAUTH2 with an external authorization server.
(Not sure BFF is really the right term here but I hope my meaning is clear enough)

After login and authorization, I would like to make a call to a REST API which is secured by the same authorization server and I need the user credentials (JWT) from the login.

FE -> BFF -> Ext API

How can I pass along these credentials in the BFF REST controller?

I have found a suggestion to get the token from the request headers and manually add this to the backend call request. But in my case, Spring is using session-based security and the token is neither in the headers nor in the principal nor in the session.
(I could maybe force Spring to use stateless security, but the approach seems questionable)

Am I doing this entirely wrong?

This is what I would like to do:

```
    @GetMapping("/fromApi")
    public String getValueFromApi(){
        RestTemplate api = new RestTemplate();
        // this call needs to have the "Authorization: Bearer token" header set
        Map response = api.getForObject("https://secure.backend.api/giveme", Map.class);
        // will throw: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [{"error":"authorization not provided"}]
        return "Entries: " + response.size();
    }
```

These are my dependencies:

```
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.4.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.3.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After another day of googling, I have actually found a solution:

1. the token is available in the @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient client and can be injected into controller method
2. my case of token forwarding/delegation/impersonation is described here: https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

The described solution does work for my case.